# How to combine objects with the same Key/Value and summing like values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I currently have an array of objects that looks similar to this where the dates are out of order and each object has the same keys:

```
let mainArray = [

{Name: 'John Doe', Date: '2022-1-1', 'Water': 5, 'Chips': 4,'Pizza': 0, 'HotDog': 0},
{Name: 'John Doe', Date: '2022-1-1', 'Water': 2, 'Chips': 0,'Pizza': 1, 'HotDog': 1},
{Name: 'John Doe', Date: '2022-1-5', 'Water': 0, 'Chips': 0, 'Pizza': 6, 'HotDog': 4},
{Name: 'John Doe', Date: '2022-1-1', 'Water': 5, 'Chips': 0, 'Pizza': 0, 'HotDog': 2},
{Name: 'Max Dow', Date: '2022-2-7', 'Water': 5, 'Soda': 4, 'Pizza': 0, 'HotDog': 0},
{Name: 'Max Dow', Date: '2022-2-7', 'Water': 0, 'Soda': 4, 'Pizza': 2, 'HotDog': 1},
{Name: 'Max Dow', Date: '2022-1-1', 'Water': 1, 'Soda': 1, 'Pizza': 0, 'HotDog': 0},
]
```

And I would like to combine objects if they share the same name and date. When combining those objects I am also trying to sum like key values together.

The result would look like this:

```
let mainArray = [

{Name: 'John Doe', Date: '2022-1-1', 'Water': 12, 'Chips': 4, 'Pizza': 1, 'HotDog': 3},
{Name: 'John Doe', Date: '2022-1-5', 'Water': 0, 'Chips': 0, 'Pizza': 6, 'HotDog': 4},
{Name: 'Max Dow', Date: '2022-2-7', 'Water': 5, 'Soda': 8, 'Pizza': 2, 'HotDog': 1},
{Name: 'Max Dow', Date: '2022-1-1', 'Water': 1, 'Soda': 1, 'Pizza': 0, 'HotDog': 0},
]
```

I was able to build a function that worked only if the object name and date were in order next to each other however I was unable to find a way to organize all objects by both name and date.

```
let newObjectArray = []
  let currentObject = {}
  let currentName = ""
  let currentDate = ""

  for (let i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) {


    if (i === 0) {
      currentObject = mainArray[0]
      currentName = mainArray[0]["Name"]
      currentDate = mainArray[0]["Date"]


    } else if (  
      mainArray[i]["Name"] === currentName &&
      mainArray[i]["Date"] === currentDate
    ) {
  
      //ensures name and date do not try to be summed
      for (const item in mainArray[i]) {
        if (typeof mainArray[i][item] === "number") {

          //adds item value into the current object's item
          currentObject[item] += mainArray[i][item]
        }
      }

    } else {

      //places completed object in array and places new values to check against
      newObjectArray.push(currentObject)
      currentObject = mainArray[i]
      currentName = mainArray[i]["Name"]
      currentDate = mainArray[i]["Date"]
    }

    //Makes sure the last Object is pushed 
    if (i + 1 === mainArray.length) {
      newObjectArray.push(currentObject)
    }

  }
```

My current function gets me close but the result looks like this where only the values next to each other combine.

```
let newObjectsArray = [

    {Name: 'John Doe', Date: '2022-1-1', 'Water': 7, 'Chips': 4, 'Pizza': 1, 'HotDog': 1},
    {Name: 'John Doe', Date: '2022-1-5', 'Water': 0, 'Chips': 0, 'Pizza': 6, 'HotDog': 4},
    {Name: 'John Doe', Date: '2022-1-1', 'Water': 5, 'Chips': 0, 'Pizza': 0, 'HotDog': 2},
    {Name: 'Max Dow', Date: '2022-2-7', 'Water': 5, 'Soda': 8, 'Pizza': 2, 'HotDog': 1},
    {Name: 'Max Dow', Date: '2022-1-1', 'Water': 1, 'Soda': 1, 'Pizza': 0, 'HotDog': 0},
    ]
```

If there is a proper way to combine such objects that would be ideal. I would also be able to solve this problem if I could sort the objects by name/date.

Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: if you want I can give a different answer using Array.reduce

Comment: Yes please if you could!

Comment: since the question is closed. i grouped the object on the combination of name and date and then got the values of final object https://codeshare.io/8pVK8J